# How do it get id of artist using spotifyr?

Tags: r, api

I am trying to get ids of artist based on artist name, album, etc. cannot seem to find a way to do so. Please help me with it. I do not need the entire program spoon fed, just the part on how to return id either through album name or artist name or both.

All of your help is much appreciated.

I have looked into documentation in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spotifyr/spotifyr.pdf still nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```
artist = "enya"
df = spotifyr::get_artist_audio_features(artist)
names(df)
 [1] "artist_name"                  "artist_id"                    "album_id"                    
 [4] "album_type"                   "album_images"                 "album_release_date"          
 [7] "album_release_year"           "album_release_date_precision" "danceability"                
[10] "energy"                       "key"                          "loudness"                    
[13] "mode"                         "speechiness"                  "acousticness"                
[16] "instrumentalness"             "liveness"                     "valence"                     
[19] "tempo"                        "track_id"                     "analysis_url"                
[22] "time_signature"               "artists"                      "available_markets"           
[25] "disc_number"                  "duration_ms"                  "explicit"                    
[28] "track_href"                   "is_local"                     "track_name"                  
[31] "track_preview_url"            "track_number"                 "type"                        
[34] "track_uri"                    "external_urls.spotify"        "album_name"                  
[37] "key_name"                     "mode_name"                    "key_mode"                    
View(df)
```

You can see that field `artist_id` is returned.
In this example:

```
print(df$artist_id[1])
"6uothxMWeLWIhsGeF7cyo4"
```

I hope it helps.